# Como obtener el tercer objeto, firebase?

Tags: firebase

Actualmente tengo el siguiente nodo (some_key3):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener los objetos tipo1, tipo2, es decir llegar a recorrer mediante firebase el objeto `"-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv"`

Lo tengo de la siguiente forma:
donde id_zona_parqueo es `some_key3` y id_categoria es `"-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv"`

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref('tablazona')
      .child(parqueo_seleccionado.id_zona_parqueo)
      .orderByChild(parqueo_seleccionado.id_categoria)
      .on('value', snapshot => this.obtenertablaPrecios(snapshot.val()))
```

Tengo el siguiente método para recorrer lo obtenido de ese query.

```
obtenertablaPrecios(tabla_precio_parqueo){  
      for(let i in tabla_precio_parqueo){
        console.log(tabla_precio_parqueo[i]);
        this.listado_parqueos.push({
          id: i,
          nombre: tabla_precio_parqueo[i].nombre,
          precio: tabla_precio_parqueo[i].precio
        })
      }

    },
```

pero en consola me imprime de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

básicamente al recorrer en el for, necesito que me imprima por individual los objetos tipo1, tipo2

Comment: ¿Habrá **siempre y sólo** `tipo1` y  un `tipo2` o bien lo que se pretende es guardar un array de objetos que pueden ser 1, 2, 3, n...? En ese caso tienes problema con la forma en que estás ordenando los datos. ¿Por qué mejor no guardar un array de objetos y entonces recorrerlo? La estructura actual te obliga a hacer algo así: `tabla_precio_parqueo[i].tipo1` para acceder a los datos del primer objeto y `tabla_precio_parqueo[i].tipo2` para el segundo. Pero el código no es funcional si hay casos en los que existirá un `tipo3` o un `tipoN`. O sea, el código no es dinámico debido a la estructura.

Comment: Debe ser dinámico, muchas gracias.

Comment: Entonces es evidente que debes cambiar la estructura, poniendo un array de objetos, algo como `[{"nombre":"tipo1", "precio":15}, {"nombre":"tipo2", "precio":25}, {"nombre":"tipo3", "precio":55}]` entonces podrás hacer un recorrido de ese array de objetos e imprimir los datos que quieras. Con la estructura que tienes, dado que tienes claves nombradas como `tipo1, tipo2` es imposible leer los datos dinámicamente.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que mediante firebase me la retorne de esa forma o que otra forma seria, de antemano muchas gracias.